# EIGRP FD not the same in topology table

Tags: cisco, eigrp

In EIGRP when showing topology table, i notice in some entries are like below:

```
P 10.1.6.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 793600
            via 10.1.2.2 (2195456/281600), Serial0/0/0
           via 10.1.3.2 (77081600/281600), Serial0/0/1
```

It seems the successor should be 10.1.2.2, but why its FD shows 2195456, not equal to 793600?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you manipulate the various k-values in order to affect route preference, this sort of output will sometimes be displayed until you reset your EIGRP neighbors. You can accomplish this by entering the following command(assuming Cisco gear): *clear ip eigrp (AS#) neighbors* where *(AS#)* is the EIGRP autonomous system number. The few times I have seen output similar to that posted(all in lab scenarios, btw), this has fixed it.